# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, nsuserdefaults, exc-bad-access

I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSUserDefaults :

```
NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[pref setObject:oldLogin forKey:@"login"];
[pref setObject:oldMotdepasse forKey:@"pass"];
[pref setObject:@"OK" forKey:@"opening"];
```

Where oldLogin and oldMotdepasse are UITextField.

I didn't get this error before, it's very strange. The error appears on the first setObject.

Thanks to read me!

EDIT : now I've got another error argh :

```
-[NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3b2d0
2012-01-16 10:32:02.601 emars[60602:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3b2d0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb75a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0110b313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb90bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f28966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f28522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   emars                               0x00008ddf -[ThirdViewController connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 932
    6   Foundation                          0x0006a112 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFinishLoading] + 108
    7   Foundation                          0x0006a06b _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 133
```

**EDIT :**
Okay, I used oldLogin as a UITextfield. I just change its type to NSString and delete the .text...

Comment: Check if oldLogin is a valid obj..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just put a UITextField into NSUserDefaults that won't work. You have to get the string value from the UITextField and put that into NSUserDefaults. `[prefs setObject:oldLogion.text forKey:@"login"]`

Comment: OK thanks, I already forget that but now I have a SIGABRT signal on the same line ...

Comment: check that oldLogin and oldMotdepasse are valid and really are UITextFiled object. And have you enabled NSZombie?

Comment: How Can I check the validity? I only have this error, Do I need to activate the zombie? :-)

Comment: `-[NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3b2d0` means your oldLogin or odMotdepasse is not a UITextField it's a NSString! It looks like you messed up with UITextField and NSString somewhere.

Comment: you're completely right, I used oldLogin as a NSString but it was a UITextfield ;-) Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to store the text in the text fields? If so then it should be

```
NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[pref setObject:oldLogin.text forKey:@"login"];
[pref setObject:oldMotdepasse.text forKey:@"pass"];
[pref setObject:@"OK" forKey:@"opening"];
```

Comment: 7KV7 : Thanks! Now I have a SIGABRT signal :-S

Answer (score 2):

from `NSUserDefault` documentation.

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

you are trying to store the UITextField.. which is wrong .. So would suggest you to insert the text values of `UITextField` instead storing the whole object.

Answer (score 1):

There are Two things need to fix in this

1. for text Field write `oldMotdepasse.text` and `oldLogin.text`
2. At the end also synchnorize it `[pref synchronize]`

E.g:

```
NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[pref setObject:oldLogin.text forKey:@"login"];
[pref setObject:oldMotdepasse.text forKey:@"pass"];
[pref setObject:@"OK" forKey:@"opening"];
[pref synchronize];
```

Comment: hundred of thanks :D I just forget to put .text, I was shure that it doesn't request it but.... Thanks

Comment: hum now I have a SIGABRT signal on the same line :-/

Comment: Have you connect the textField to outlet and make sure you did not release textfield also try this thing when you are going to setvalues [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",oldLogin.text];

Comment: Thanks dark !I used oldLogin as a NSString but it was a UITextfield ;-)